# make: *** No rule to make target 'loader64.o', needed by 'wind64.exe'. Stop

Tags: makefile, msys2

Trying to compile WindowsD project with MSYS2-MINGW64 and get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'loader64.o', needed by 'wind64.exe'.  Stop.
```

For the first time I am dealing with a makefile, I have tried many solutions to the problem that I found on the Internet, but without success..

How to resolve this problem?

Makefile problem part:

```
...

%.o : %.rc
    windres $< $@

...

ifneq ($(LOADERS),)
loader32.rc: win7sp1x86/termdd.sys
    echo -e '#include "defs.h"\nLOADER_ID RCDATA "$<"' | windres -o $@
loader64.rc: win7sp1x64/termdd.sys
    echo -e '#include "defs.h"\nLOADER_ID RCDATA "$<"' | windres -o $@
endif

...
```

Comment: Does `win7sp1x64/termdd.sys` exist?

Comment: Tangentially, prefer `printf` over `echo -e`.